# Validate method is not firing at first click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, aurelia, semantic-ui

I am validating a form using semantic ui but it is only working when I double click a  button rather than single click. Here is my code:

How to validate form at first click of send button.

```js
validate() {
  $('.ui.form')
    .form({
      inline: false,
      on: 'blur',
      fields: {
        to: {
          identifier: 'to',
          rules: [{
            type: 'email',
            prompt: 'Please enter email address'
          }]
        },
        comments: {
          identifier: 'comments',
          rules: [{
            type: 'empty',
            prompt: 'Please enter comments'
          }]
        }
      },
      onSuccess: function(event) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/api/controller",
          cache: false,
          async: false,
          success: function(data) {

          },
          error: function(err) {
            console.log(err + "err");
          }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
      },
      onFailure: function(event) {
        alert("fail");
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="ui container right aligned">
  <button id="btnSuccess" class="ui primary submit button form" 
    click.delegate="validate()">Send</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You likely need  `event.preventDefault();` in the form submit and not in the return of the async - additionally add `type="button"` to your button

Comment: when click on button at first time form is not validate after click form successfully validate .

Comment: Thanks @michal After applying your code, still it is giving the same issue.

Comment: Can you please post whole source code? You are using jQuery the right way. I used to make same mistakes so I am 99% sure that you can fire the validation on the second click because you are actually binding the validation on the first click.

Comment: Did my answer help you? :) Could you please mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Because this code snippet:

```
validate() {
  $('.ui.form')
}
```

On the first click binds `.form` to your `$('.ui.form')` element. On second click you fire the validation because it is already bound.

**How to fix it:**

```
// This will add event listetner itself. You don't need to call anything
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.ui.form')
    .form({
      inline: false,
      on: 'blur',
      fields: {
        to: {
          identifier: 'to',
          rules: [{
            type: 'email',
            prompt: 'Please enter email address'
          }]
        },
        comments: {
          identifier: 'comments',
          rules: [{
            type: 'empty',
            prompt: 'Please enter comments'
          }]
        }
      },
      onSuccess: function(event) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/api/controller",
          cache: false,
          async: false,
          success: function(data) {

          },
          error: function(err) {
            console.log(err + "err");
          }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
      },
      onFailure: function(event) {
        alert("fail");
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
});

<!-- Notice that i removed the onClick handler -->
<div class="ui container right aligned">
  <button id="btnSuccess" class="ui primary submit button form">Send</button>
</div>
```